# Play Audio when application is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have read other threads in SO, but seems none of them suits my case.

My application will play an audio file when receiving a push notification.
If my app is in foreground, it is fine. But when I put the phone to sleep by pressing the lock button.

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                         mode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault
                           routeSharingPolicy:AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicyDefault
                                      options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"###########START set category with error: %@",error.description);
                    [audioSession setActive:true error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"###########START set active with error: %@",error.description);
```

An error shows when I try to activate my audio session.

```
###########START set category with error: (null) 2019-07-05 15:51:35.149386+0800 [1936:804557] 
###########START set active with error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561015905 "(null)"
```

error 561015905 is AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartPlaying

from Apple document:

This error type can occur if the app’s Information property list does not permit audio use, or if the app is in the background and using a category which does not allow background audio.

but I did enable audio in background in in Capabilities, and also permit audio use.

anything wrong with my category setting??

I checked the console log. I got this

```
default 17:10:19.487601 +0800   mediaserverd    1242: { "action":"set_category", "session":{"ID":"0x1ac7d","PID":2181,"name":"MY_APP"}, "details":{"key":"AudioCategory","value":"MediaPlayback"} }
default 17:10:19.489471 +0800   mediaserverd    2832: { "action":"set_property", "session":{"ID":"0x1ac7d","PID":2181,"name":"MY_APP"}, "details":{"key":"InterruptionStyle","value":"Mix with others"} }
default 17:10:19.491276 +0800   mediaserverd    2832: { "action":"set_property", "session":{"ID":"0x1ac7d","PID":2181,"name":"MY_APP"}, "details":{"key":"WantsToPauseSpokenAudio","value":false} }
default 17:10:19.494890 +0800   mediaserverd    2919: { "action":"activate", "session":{"ID":"0x1ac7d","PID":2181,"name":"MY_APP"}, "details":"entry" }
default 17:10:19.501012 +0800   mediaserverd    -CMSUtilities- CMSUtility_IsAllowedToStartPlaying: CMSession: Client sid:0x1ac7d, MY_APP(2181), 'prim' with category MediaPlayback and mode Default and mixable does not have assertions to start mixable playback
default 17:10:19.501838 +0800   mediaserverd    -CMSessionMgr- _CMSessionBeginInterruption_WithFlags: CMSession: CMSessionBeginInterruption failed as client 'sid:0x1ac7d, MY_APP(2181), 'prim'' has insufficient privileges to take control
error   17:10:19.503217 +0800   mediaserverd    259: { "action":"cm_session_begin_interruption", "error":"translating CM session error", "session":{"ID":"0x1ac7d","PID":2181,"name":"MY_APP"}, "details":{"calling_line":2949,"error_code":-16980,"error_string":"Operation denied. Cannot start playing"} }
```

Comment: Take a look at - https://www.sagorin.org/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/

Comment: its case is "Music must be playing". In my case, I want play audio when receiving push notification

Comment: You mean a notification sound ??

Comment: No, an audio file which download immediately when it receive the notification

Comment: You mean your notification payload will contain a audio file , which should download and play

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, I should wake up my phone with VoIP Notification instead of the normal Push Notification